# How to install Babel English?

Tags: miktex, installing, babel, languages

I use MikTex Update to install, some security configurations make me can only install package in Update, not Package Manager.
I install all package in the Update, but the system show error that I do not install babel english... 
How can I install Babel english?

Comment: @Chistian Hupfer: The .ldf files are no more in ‘generic’ babel, but in `babel-english` for the english language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure it isn't already installed — I thought it was part of the ‘basic’ installation. If you cannot have administrator privileges to install with the Package Manager, you can download from a repositoy `babel-english.tar.lzma`. Unzip it (twice) to get a `texmf` folder. You just have to copy the contents of this folder `at the root` of the MiKTeX distribution — the default being `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\` if you have the 64 bit version. For the 32 bit version, replace Program Files with `Program Files (x86)`.

It only remains to refresh the FNDB (via MiKTeX Options). Note that in case of an update to `babel-english`, you will have to redo these steps, as MiKTeX won't consider the package as ‘installed’.